# tidyr not count NA in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

How to not count NA's in the following code!

Dataframe

```
df<-read.table(text="
Name per1 per2 per3
a1 000 xxx 230
a1 xxx 000 NA
a2 000 340 xxx
a3 000 xxx NA",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)
```

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

df %>% gather(key, value, -Name) %>%
  mutate(value = 
     ifelse(is.na(value) | !(value %in% c("000", "xxx")), "Others", value)) %>%
  dcast(Name~value, fun.aggregate = length)
```

Issue: Others count for NA'S too

Comment: Why not just remove the "Others" column from the result or filter it out before `dcast`?

Comment: @hpesoj626 others is required but not with NA's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you can use `filter` to remove `NA`s after `gather`ing

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Name) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(value %in% c("000", "xxx"), value, "Others")) %>%
  dcast(., Name ~ value, length)
#  Name 000 Others xxx
#1   a1   2      1   2
#2   a2   1      1   1
#3   a3   1      0   1
```

---

Or, if you want to count the `NA`s per 'Name' too you can use `case_when` (instead of another `ifelse`) an convert them to strings

```
df %>%
  gather(key, value, -Name) %>%
  mutate(value =
           case_when(
             value %in% c("000", "xxx") ~ value,
             is.na(value) ~ "NA",
             TRUE ~ "Others"
           )) %>%
  dcast(Name ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)
#  Name 000 NA Others xxx
#1   a1   2  1      1   2
#2   a2   1  0      1   1
#3   a3   1  1      0   1
```